# google search is showing index of / instead of title and description

Tags: google-search

i have deployed my website online. if i type domain name of my website in google search bar instead of showing title and metadata a different text is shown such as

**Index of/**

**[DIR], IELTS/, 2019-02-03 12:11, -. [ ], IELTS.zip, 2019-02-03 11:59, 71M. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at ieltsbooks.co.in Port 80.**

my index.html file is in root directory

Domain name: http://ieltsbooks.co.in

i have indexed my website to google by submitting sitemap.xml file to google console search.

Comment: Google indexing is not immediate. You must wait until the google bot visits and indexes your page.

Comment: i have checked on Google console search. my pages are indexed. it's just not showing appropriate title and meta data on Google search.